# Galleria: show last image

Tags: javascript, galleria

Here is the current Galleria API: http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/api/methods/

Given this API, I want to display the picture I just uploaded and pushed to galleria:

```
 Galleria.get(0).push({
     image: '<%= @photo.photo.url %>',
     thumb: '<%= @photo.photo.thumb.url %>',
     title: '<%= @photo.title %>'
 });
```

I was thinking about simply using the `.show( index )` method, but I don't see how to get the index without having to count the children of some container...

**Do you see a way to get the index of the last picture using the api?**

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

Looking at the galleria object, I guess I could access "private" variables like _data and get the length... but if you find a better way, go ahead ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Galleria.get(0).getDataLength() - 1;
```

internals:

```
getDataLength = function () {
    return this._data.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this method :) It probably wouldn't hurt if they added first and last to the api ^^.

Comment: @Robin There are some undocumented methods (maybe legacy, unimplemented or buggy). You can find them with [chatzilla's dumpObject](http://hg.mozilla.org/chatzilla/file/59b46c0bf716/js/lib/utils.js#l136) `alert(dumpObject(Galleria.get(0)))` or `window.a = Galleria.get(0)` and lookup `window.a` in the debuggingtool of your choice (Firebug: DOM-Tab).

Comment: Yeah, I usually just use console.log(...) and take a look at the object in chrome. I just missed this method ;) thanks